# Combine N-gram model with Bag of Word approach

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, n-gram

I'm trying to classify offensive and non-offensive sentences using N-gram model with a set of training data. I would like to know if there are any approach to add bad word dictionary to the n-gram model.

I'm very new to machine learning and recently started this project. I want to know what kind of the methods are available for this problem if the above approach is not possible.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why would you want to? A bag-of-words model is essentially a special case of an N-gram model, one where N=1. A bag of words model is essentially an n-gram model without any information about word position.

Comment: In other words, they are the same approach, with N-grams being an extension of the basic bag-of-words.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Since n-gram model would only concern about the data in training set, I wanted to make sure that all possible bad words would have been captured by integrating such a list. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What? I don't understand. What does splitting your data into training and testing sets have to do with bag-of-words vs n-grams?

Comment: What if a bad word in test data set would not be included in training set? Then in testing the model that sentence would be classified as not offensive right?

Comment: Yes, there almost always is the issue of unseen data. But splitting into training/testing sets is to check if your model parameters are over-fitting. It also is used to calculate better estimates of metrics, since a model is usually baised towards the training data. But at the end, you will use a model that is trained on all your data. Train/test split and cross validation is to give you a better sense of the generalizability of your model.